# Recommendations for recent books on the fundamentals of graphic design?

Tags: book, reference-request

I am a layperson and want to develop a more solid foundation about the principles of graphic design. In consequence, I wanted to see which introductory books people with a more formal background in graphic design would recommend to get started. I know that a similar questions has already been asked [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29553/introductory-books-on-graphic-design), but the responses are now close to ten years old and hence likely outdated. I imagine quite a lot has changed since then. Can you recommend any more recent materials?

Comment: Design is not a technological science. Some principles have some thousands of years, so, yes some can be outdated if you are referring to technical aspects, like CGI, but "design" itself is not necessarily "outdatable".

Comment: @Rafael: I agree that some principles such as the golden ratio and geometric principles are more or less universal, but I'd say that tastes in art and design tend to change over time, and I suspect that is reflected in the teaching materials. The use and significance of color, for instance, differs between cultures. And the crimes against aesthetics commited by architects in the 70s marr our cities to this day =P. Or old Germanic script: complex, ornate, almost unreadable, but the height of fashion some hundreds of years ago.

Comment: The *principles* used in design are timeless - color, balance, proximity, typography, etc... The question you linked to is still *very* valid for *principles*. However, what you seem to be asking is what are current **trends**. That's a hard topic to write *books* about since trends can change year to year. You'd most likely be better served by asking Google and reading web content since it's far, far, more dynamic and will be more up to date. Books take a good 6 months or more from concept to publication.. in that time any "trend" may have already died.

Comment: After you'll read all this theoretical material, principles, good practices, ratios, grids, dashes ... then the clients come, and its urgent, and you find out how it works in real life :))))